# libvirtError: internal error Cannot find suitable CPU model for given data

Tags: openstack, kvm, libvirt

I am trying to run a simple instance after a fresh installation of OpenStack. The instance cannot start and in the log I found "libvirtError: internal error Cannot find suitable CPU model for given data". Please help.

Some info:

libvirt.x86_64                                                                             0.10.2.6-5.el6.centos.alt

qemu-kvm.x86_64                                                                                     2:0.12.1.2-2.355.0.1.el6.centos.6

CentOS release 6.4 (Final). (Linux 3.4.54-8.el6.centos.alt.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 23 17:29:30 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

```
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm  --cpu ?
x86       Opteron_G5  AMD Opteron 63xx class CPU                      
x86       Opteron_G4  AMD Opteron 62xx class CPU                      
x86       Opteron_G3  AMD Opteron 23xx (Gen 3 Class Opteron)          
x86       Opteron_G2  AMD Opteron 22xx (Gen 2 Class Opteron)          
x86       Opteron_G1  AMD Opteron 240 (Gen 1 Class Opteron)           
x86          Haswell  Intel Core Processor (Haswell)                  
x86      SandyBridge  Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge)                
x86         Westmere  Westmere E56xx/L56xx/X56xx (Nehalem-C)          
x86          Nehalem  Intel Core i7 9xx (Nehalem Class Core i7)       
x86           Penryn  Intel Core 2 Duo P9xxx (Penryn Class Core 2)    
x86           Conroe  Intel Celeron_4x0 (Conroe/Merom Class Core 2)   
x86      cpu64-rhel5  QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel5)          
x86      cpu64-rhel6  QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6)          
x86             n270  Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz          
x86           athlon  QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.12.1                 
x86         pentium3                                                  
x86         pentium2                                                  
x86          pentium                                                  
x86              486                                                  
x86          coreduo  Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2600  @ 2.16GHz 
x86           qemu32  QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.12.1                 
x86            kvm64  Common KVM processor                            
x86         core2duo  Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7700  @ 2.40GHz 
x86           phenom  AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor         
x86           qemu64  QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.12.1 
Recognized CPUID flags:
  f_edx: pbe ia64 tm ht ss sse2 sse fxsr mmx acpi ds clflush pn pse36 pat cmov mca pge mtrr sep apic cx8 mce pae msr tsc pse de vme fpu
  f_ecx: hypervisor rdrand f16c avx osxsave xsave aes tsc-deadline popcnt movbe x2apic sse4.2|sse4_2 sse4.1|sse4_1 dca pcid pdcm xtpr cx16 fma cid ssse3 tm2 est smx vmx ds_cpl monitor dtes64 pclmulqdq|pclmuldq pni|sse3
  extf_edx: 3dnow 3dnowext lm|i64 rdtscp pdpe1gb fxsr_opt|ffxsr fxsr mmx mmxext nx|xd pse36 pat cmov mca pge mtrr syscall apic cx8 mce pae msr tsc pse de vme fpu
  extf_ecx: perfctr_nb perfctr_core topoext tbm nodeid_msr tce fma4 lwp wdt skinit xop ibs osvw 3dnowprefetch misalignsse sse4a abm cr8legacy extapic svm cmp_legacy lahf_lm
```

And:

```
virsh -r capabilities
<capabilities>

  <host>
    <uuid>44454c4c-4400-104d-8030-cac04f584731</uuid>
    <cpu>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
      <model>Penryn</model>
      <vendor>Intel</vendor>
      <topology sockets='1' cores='2' threads='1'/>
      <feature name='pdcm'/>
      <feature name='xtpr'/>
      <feature name='tm2'/>
      <feature name='est'/>
      <feature name='smx'/>
      <feature name='vmx'/>
      <feature name='ds_cpl'/>
      <feature name='monitor'/>
      <feature name='dtes64'/>
      <feature name='pbe'/>
      <feature name='tm'/>
      <feature name='ht'/>
      <feature name='ss'/>
      <feature name='acpi'/>
      <feature name='ds'/>
      <feature name='vme'/>
    </cpu>
    <power_management>
      <suspend_mem/>
      <suspend_disk/>
    </power_management>
    <migration_features>
      <live/>
      <uri_transports>
        <uri_transport>tcp</uri_transport>
      </uri_transports>
    </migration_features>
    <topology>
      <cells num='1'>
        <cell id='0'>
          <cpus num='2'>
            <cpu id='0'/>
            <cpu id='1'/>
          </cpus>
        </cell>
      </cells>
    </topology>
    <secmodel>
      <model>none</model>
      <doi>0</doi>
    </secmodel>
    <secmodel>
      <model>dac</model>
      <doi>0</doi>
    </secmodel>
  </host>

  <guest>
    <os_type>hvm</os_type>
    <arch name='i686'>
      <wordsize>32</wordsize>
      <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      <machine>rhel6.4.0</machine>
      <machine canonical='rhel6.4.0'>pc</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.3.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.2.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.1.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.0.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel5.5.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel5.4.4</machine>
      <machine>rhel5.4.0</machine>
      <domain type='qemu'>
      </domain>
      <domain type='kvm'>
        <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      </domain>
    </arch>
    <features>
      <cpuselection/>
      <deviceboot/>
      <pae/>
      <nonpae/>
      <acpi default='on' toggle='yes'/>
      <apic default='on' toggle='no'/>
    </features>
  </guest>

  <guest>
    <os_type>hvm</os_type>
    <arch name='x86_64'>
      <wordsize>64</wordsize>
      <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      <machine>rhel6.4.0</machine>
      <machine canonical='rhel6.4.0'>pc</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.3.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.2.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.1.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel6.0.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel5.5.0</machine>
      <machine>rhel5.4.4</machine>
      <machine>rhel5.4.0</machine>
      <domain type='qemu'>
      </domain>
      <domain type='kvm'>
        <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      </domain>
    </arch>
    <features>
      <cpuselection/>
      <deviceboot/>
      <acpi default='on' toggle='yes'/>
      <apic default='on' toggle='no'/>
    </features>
  </guest>

</capabilities>
```

And:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8200  @ 2.66GHz
stepping    : 6
microcode   : 0x60f
cpu MHz     : 2659.800
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips    : 5319.60
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8200  @ 2.66GHz
stepping    : 6
microcode   : 0x60f
cpu MHz     : 2659.800
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips    : 5319.60
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

And the file /usr/share/libvirt/cpu_map.xml looks like:

```
<cpus>
  <arch name='x86'>
    <!-- vendor definitions -->
    <vendor name='Intel' string='GenuineIntel'/>
    <vendor name='AMD' string='AuthenticAMD'/>

    <!-- standard features, EDX -->
    <feature name='fpu'> <!-- CPUID_FP87 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000001'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='vme'> <!-- CPUID_VME -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000002'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='de'> <!-- CPUID_DE -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000004'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pse'> <!-- CPUID_PSE -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000008'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='tsc'> <!-- CPUID_TSC -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000010'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='msr'> <!-- CPUID_MSR -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000020'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pae'> <!-- CPUID_PAE -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000040'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='mce'> <!-- CPUID_MCE -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000080'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='cx8'> <!-- CPUID_CX8 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000100'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='apic'> <!-- CPUID_APIC -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000200'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='sep'> <!-- CPUID_SEP -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00000800'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='mtrr'> <!-- CPUID_MTRR -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00001000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pge'> <!-- CPUID_PGE -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00002000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='mca'> <!-- CPUID_MCA -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00004000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='cmov'> <!-- CPUID_CMOV -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00008000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pat'> <!-- CPUID_PAT -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00010000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pse36'> <!-- CPUID_PSE36 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00020000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pn'> <!-- CPUID_PN -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00040000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='clflush'> <!-- CPUID_CLFLUSH -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00080000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='ds'> <!-- CPUID_DTS -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00200000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='acpi'> <!-- CPUID_ACPI -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00400000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='mmx'> <!-- CPUID_MMX -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x00800000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='fxsr'> <!-- CPUID_FXSR -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x01000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='sse'> <!-- CPUID_SSE -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x02000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='sse2'> <!-- CPUID_SSE2 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x04000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='ss'> <!-- CPUID_SS -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x08000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='ht'> <!-- CPUID_HT -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x10000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='tm'> <!-- CPUID_TM -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x20000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='ia64'> <!-- CPUID_IA64 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x40000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pbe'> <!-- CPUID_PBE -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' edx='0x80000000'/>
    </feature>

    <!-- standard features, ECX -->
    <feature name='pni'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_SSE3 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000001'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pclmuldq'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000002'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='dtes64'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000004'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='monitor'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_MONITOR -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000008'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='ds_cpl'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_DSCPL -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000010'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='vmx'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_VMX -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000020'/>
    </feature>
     <feature name='smx'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000040'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='est'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_EST -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000080'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='tm2'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_TM2 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000100'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='ssse3'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_SSSE3 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000200'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='cid'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_CID -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00000400'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='fma'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00001000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='cx16'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_CX16 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00002000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='xtpr'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_XTPR -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00004000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pdcm'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00008000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='dca'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_DCA -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00040000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='sse4.1'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_SSE41 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00080000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='sse4.2'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_SSE42 -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00100000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='x2apic'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_X2APIC -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00200000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='movbe'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00400000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='popcnt'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_POPCNT -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x00800000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='tsc-deadline'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x01000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='aes'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x02000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='xsave'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x04000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='osxsave'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x08000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='avx'>
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x10000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='hypervisor'> <!-- CPUID_EXT_HYPERVISOR -->
      <cpuid function='0x00000001' ecx='0x80000000'/>
    </feature>

    <!-- extended features, EDX -->
    <feature name='syscall'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_SYSCALL -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x00000800'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='nx'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_NX -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x00100000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='mmxext'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_MMXEXT -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x00400000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='fxsr_opt'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_FFXSR -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x02000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='pdpe1gb'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_PDPE1GB -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x04000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='rdtscp'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_RDTSCP -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x08000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='lm'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_LM -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x20000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='3dnowext'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_3DNOWEXT -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x40000000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='3dnow'> <!-- CPUID_EXT2_3DNOW -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' edx='0x80000000'/>
    </feature>

    <!-- extended features, ECX -->
    <feature name='lahf_lm'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_LAHF_LM -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000001'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='cmp_legacy'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_CMP_LEG -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000002'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='svm'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_SVM -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000004'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='extapic'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_EXTAPIC -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000008'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='cr8legacy'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_CR8LEG -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000010'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='abm'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_ABM -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000020'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='sse4a'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_SSE4A -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000040'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='misalignsse'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_MISALIGNSSE -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000080'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='3dnowprefetch'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_3DNOWPREFETCH -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000100'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='osvw'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_OSVW -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000200'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='ibs'>
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000400'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='xop'>
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00000800'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='skinit'> <!-- CPUID_EXT3_SKINIT -->
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00001000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='wdt'>
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00002000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='fma4'>
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00010000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='cvt16'>
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00040000'/>
    </feature>
    <feature name='nodeid_msr'>
      <cpuid function='0x80000001' ecx='0x00080000'/>
    </feature>

    <!-- models -->
    <model name='486'>
      <feature name='fpu'/>
      <feature name='vme'/>
      <feature name='pse'/>
    </model>

    <!-- Intel-based QEMU generic CPU models -->
    <model name='pentium'>
      <model name='486'/>
      <feature name='de'/>
      <feature name='tsc'/>
      <feature name='msr'/>
      <feature name='mce'/>
      <feature name='cx8'/>
      <feature name='mmx'/>
    </model>

    <model name='pentium2'>
      <model name='pentium'/>
      <feature name='pae'/>
      <feature name='sep'/>
      <feature name='mtrr'/>
      <feature name='pge'/>
      <feature name='mca'/>
      <feature name='cmov'/>
      <feature name='pat'/>
      <feature name='pse36'/>
      <feature name='fxsr'/>
    </model>

    <model name='pentium3'>
      <model name='pentium2'/>
      <feature name='sse'/>
    </model>

    <model name='pentiumpro'>
      <feature name='fpu'/>
      <feature name='de'/>
      <feature name='pse'/>
      <feature name='tsc'/>
      <feature name='msr'/>
      <feature name='pae'/>
      <feature name='mce'/>
      <feature name='cx8'/>
      <feature name='apic'/>
      <feature name='sep'/>
      <feature name='pge'/>
      <feature name='cmov'/>
      <feature name='pat'/>
      <feature name='mmx'/>
      <feature name='fxsr'/>
      <feature name='sse'/>
      <feature name='sse2'/>
    </model>

    <model name='coreduo'>
      <model name='pentiumpro'/>
      <vendor name='Intel'/>
      <feature name='vme'/>
      <feature name='mtrr'/>
      <feature name='mca'/>
      <feature name='clflush'/>
      <feature name='pni'/>
      <feature name='monitor'/>
      <feature name='nx'/>
    </model>

    <model name='n270'>
      <model name='coreduo'/>
      <feature name='ssse3'/>
    </model>

    <model name='core2duo'>
      <model name='n270'/>
      <feature name='pse36'/>
      <feature name='syscall'/>
      <feature name='lm'/>
    </model>

    <!-- Generic QEMU CPU models -->
    <model name='qemu32'>
      <model name='pentiumpro'/>
      <feature name='pni'/>
    </model>

    <model name='kvm32'>
      <model name='qemu32'/>
      <feature name='mtrr'/>
      <feature name='mca'/>
      <feature name='pse36'/>
      <feature name='clflush'/>
    </model>

    <model name='cpu64-rhel5'>
      <model name='kvm32'/>
      <feature name='syscall'/>
      <feature name='nx'/>
      <feature name='lm'/>
    </model>

    <model name='cpu64-rhel6'>
      <model name='cpu64-rhel5'/>
      <feature name='cx16'/>
      <feature name='lahf_lm'/>
    </model>

    <model name='kvm64'>
      <model name='cpu64-rhel5'/>
      <feature name='cx16'/>
    </model>

    <model name='qemu64'>
      <model name='kvm64'/>
      <!-- These are supported only by TCG.  KVM supports them only if the
           host does.  So we leave them out:

           <feature name='popcnt'/>
           <feature name='lahf_lm'/>
           <feature name='sse4a'/>
           <feature name='abm'/>
      -->
      <feature name='svm'/>
    </model>

    <!-- Intel CPU models -->
    <model name='Conroe'>
      <model name='pentiumpro'/>
      <vendor name='Intel'/>
      <feature name='mtrr'/>
      <feature name='mca'/>
      <feature name='pse36'/>
      <feature name='clflush'/>
      <feature name='pni'/>
      <feature name='ssse3'/>
      <feature name='syscall'/>
      <feature name='nx'/>
      <feature name='lm'/>
      <feature name='lahf_lm'/>
    </model>

    <model name='Penryn'>
      <model name='Conroe'/>
      <feature name='cx16'/>
      <feature name='sse4.1'/>
    </model>

    <model name='Nehalem'>
      <model name='Penryn'/>
      <feature name='sse4.2'/>
      <feature name='popcnt'/>
    </model>

    <model name='Westmere'>
      <model name='Nehalem'/>
      <feature name='aes'/>
    </model>

    <model name='SandyBridge'>
      <model name='Westmere'/>
      <feature name='pclmuldq'/>
      <feature name='x2apic'/>
      <feature name='tsc-deadline'/>
      <feature name='xsave'/>
      <feature name='avx'/>
      <feature name='rdtscp'/>
    </model>

    <!-- AMD CPUs -->
    <model name='athlon'>
      <model name='pentiumpro'/>
      <vendor name='AMD'/>
      <feature name='vme'/>
      <feature name='mtrr'/>
      <feature name='pse36'/>
      <feature name='mmxext'/>
      <feature name='3dnowext'/>
      <feature name='3dnow'/>
    </model>

    <model name='phenom'>
      <model name='cpu64-rhel5'/>
      <vendor name='AMD'/>
      <feature name='monitor'/>
      <feature name='mmxext'/>
      <feature name='fxsr_opt'/>
      <feature name='3dnowext'/>
      <feature name='3dnow'/>
      <feature name='svm'/>
    </model>

    <model name='Opteron_G1'>
      <model name='cpu64-rhel5'/>
      <vendor name='AMD'/>
    </model>

    <model name='Opteron_G2'>
      <model name='Opteron_G1'/>
      <feature name='cx16'/>
      <feature name='rdtscp'/>
      <feature name='lahf_lm'/>
      <feature name='svm'/>
    </model>

    <model name='Opteron_G3'>
      <model name='Opteron_G2'/>
      <feature name='monitor'/>
      <feature name='popcnt'/>
      <feature name='abm'/>
      <feature name='sse4a'/>
      <feature name='misalignsse'/>
    </model>

    <model name='Opteron_G4'>
      <model name='Opteron_G2'/>
      <!-- Can't inherit from G3 because of missing "monitor"
           feature -->
      <feature name='pclmuldq'/>
      <feature name='ssse3'/>
      <feature name='sse4.1'/>
      <feature name='sse4.2'/>
      <feature name='popcnt'/>
      <feature name='aes'/>
      <feature name='xsave'/>
      <feature name='avx'/>
      <feature name='pdpe1gb'/>
      <feature name='abm'/>
      <feature name='sse4a'/>
      <feature name='misalignsse'/>
      <feature name='3dnowprefetch'/>
      <feature name='xop'/>
      <feature name='fma4'/>
    </model>
  </arch>
</cpus>
```

The only answer I have got from Openstack forum says:

"It simply means you are using wrong package and it is not supported for your architecture. Kindly see the official Centos site and try to understand if they have package available for your architecture.."

But I am not sure what it means. Do I need to get another libvirt package for CentOS that support my architecture? Is that what he meant?

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by stopping libvirt, removing all files on /var/cache/libvirt/qemu/capabilities/ and starting it again.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1160318

Works for me in Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Fixed it for me on gentoo.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `libvirt_cpu_mode=host-passthrough` in `nova.conf` might solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

This solved the problem on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
 service libvirt-bin restart
```